# When is "Set" required in lotus script when setting an environment variable

Tags: syntax, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I've inherited a nightmare of a project from the days when I can only assume LOC was an acceptable KPI in lotus script. I'm working on refactoring repetitive code after I've been asked to make a change to how our company's apps work. The code below illustrates something I don't understand about the syntax of Lotus Script -- I'm getting an error in the domino designer that on the "Control = UIDoc.Document....." line that A "Set" is required. Looking at existing code, sometimes Set is used for assignment, sometimes it is not. I'm trying to read the lotus script doc's, but haven't yet found an explanation of the difference. Any change someone could illuminate me on when Set should be used and when it should not? If it helps I have a strong C# background with some minor experience in interpreted languages like JS and PHP

```
Class DeploymentType
Private ProductName As String
Private ControlSuffix As String
Private TypeHeader As String
Private Control As NotesRichTextItem

Sub new (Product As String, Suffix As String, Header As String, UIDoc As NotesUIDocument)
    'These three assignments do not show an error without set
    ProductName = Product
    ControlSuffix = Suffix
    TypeHeader = Header
    'This assignment shows an error unless I prepend it with "Set"
    Set Control = UIDoc.Document.GetFirstItem(ProductName + ControlSuffix)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set` keyword has nothing to do with environment variables. The `UIDoc.Document` method returns an object in the [NotesDocument](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS.html) class. `Set` is required for assigning object references. Assignments to scalar variables with [simple built-in data types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/LSAZ_SUMMARY_OF_LOTUSSCRIPT_DATA_TYPES.html) (string, integer, boolean, byte, etc.) do not require `Set`.

Use `Set` for objects from the Notes product classes, any OLE or COM classes or any classes that you define in LotusScript itself.